# Jenkins Agent running in kubernetes: docker not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm running a Jenkins agent within a kubernetes cluster. The pod provisioning works fine and pipeline steps get executed. The `Jenkinsfile` defines the following stages:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'kubepods' }

    tools {
        nodejs 'nodejs'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Install NPM packages') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm ci'
            }
        }
        stage('Compile app') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm run ng build'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t local-image .'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to k8s'){
            steps {
                sh 'hostname'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when running jenkins within the cluster, Jenkins is not able to find docker and fails the build giving the following output:
`home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test@tmp/durable-1a3be3e3/script.sh: docker: not found`

I tried everything what the web provides but nothing works. A global docker installation is provided, configured by those steps:

- name: **docker**
- version: **latest**
- install method: **automatically**

The docker plugin is installed as well. What's the problem running a Jenkins agent in kubernetes?

Many thanks in advice!

Comment: which container engine is your kubernetes cluster using? if it is not docker, ist docker installed on those hosts?

Comment: Solved the problem already. Edited the `pod.yaml` to spin up a second `docker:ind` container to use for building and publishing. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you let others know the github codes? I'm in a same situation!